# Expo React Native: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, machine-learning, expo

I am trying to classify my images using a trained model in my expo react native android app When I call the predict function from a button press, sometimes my app crashes and sometimes it says:
Warn Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: Network request failed
It shows similar behavior's on both emulator and physical device(expo go)

```
const modelJSON = require("../../assets/wheatDiseaseModel/model.json");
const modelWeights = require("../../assets/wheatDiseaseModel/group1-shard.bin");


//Here's my predict function
const predict = async () => {
    // const model = await loadModel();
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights));

    const resizedImage = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
      selectedimage,
      [{ resize: { width: 224, height: 224 } }],
      { compress: 1, format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.PNG }
    );

    const response = await fetch(resizedImage);
    const imageData = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const imageTensor = tf.node.decodeImage(new Uint8Array(imageData), 3);
    setImageTensor(imageTensor);
    const prediction = model.predict(imageTensor);
    setModelPrediction(prediction);
    console.log(prediction);
  };
```

Comment: have you tried to use `try() catch` so you can catch the error. I think it may be an IP address error so try to check if the IP is correct.
also could you share with us the called API?

Comment: Yes I tried that here it is  LOG  [TypeError: Network request failed]

Comment: can you edit the question and provide the API you called when fetching the image?